# SWIG: mutable string typemap help needed

Tags: python, c, swig

This (I hope) is quite a simple issue, but despite doing some reading (I'm v. new to SWIG, and fairly green C-wise) I'm just not able to make the "connection" in my head.

I have a function from a library (legacy code, keen not to edit):

```
extern int myfunction(char *infile, char *maskfile, int check, float *median, char *msg)
```

My aim is to create a wrapper for this in Python using SWIG.

The values of the `median` and `msg` variables are changed by the C function. When the return `int != 0` then there will be some error information in the `msg` arg. Where the return `int == 0`, then `median` variable will contain a float with value assigned from `myfunction`.

This generally runs OK where the return value is 0. I use `%array_functions` and `%pointer_functions` to create the pointers needing to be passed, as per this `.i` file:

```
%module test
%include "cpointer.i"
%include "carrays.i"
%{
 #include <stdint.h>
%}

extern int myfunction(char *infile, char *maskfile, int check, float *median, char *msg)

%pointer_functions(float, floatp);
%pointer_functions(char, charp);
%array_functions(char, charArray);
```

After swig-ing, compiling and linking, I can call the function in python:

```
import test
errmsg_buffer = 1024
_infile = 'test2.dat'
infile  = imstat.new_charArray(len(_infile))
for i in xrange(len(_infile)):
    imstat.charArray_setitem(infile,i,_infile[i])
maskfile = imstat.new_charArray(1)
imstat.charArray_setitem(maskfile,0,'')
check = 0
med = imstat.new_floatp()
errmsg = imstat.new_charArray(errmsg_buffer)

out = test.myfunction(infile,maskfile,check,med,errmsg)
median = test.floatp_value(med)
```

This works sometimes, but often not - I get a lot of segfaults which are generally fixed by changing the `errmsg_buffer` length (clearly not a useful fix!). The C code that changes the `msg` string is:

```
(void)sprintf(errmsg,"file not found");
```

My main issue is in proper handling of `msg` string, which I suspect is causing the segfaults (and might be due to incorrect implementation via `new_charArray`?).

What is the best way to do this?

Can I add something to the `.i` that converts the `char *msg` into a python `str`?

Can this be done without "pre-initialising" with `new_CharArray`? I'd presumably get a buffer overflow if `errmsg_buffer` is too small.

I hope this is clear - happy to add comments for further discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your wrapper can be much simplified using SWIG. Try this SWIG interface file (details below):

```
%module test
%include "typemaps.i"
%include "cstring.i"
%apply float *OUTPUT { float *median };
%cstring_bounded_output(char *msg, 1024);
extern int myfunction(char *infile, char *maskfile, int check, float *median, char *msg);
```

Then, from python, use the module in the following way:

```
import test
infile = 'test2.dat'
maskfile = ''
check = 0
out, median, errmsg = test.myfunction(infile,maskfile,check)
if out == 0: print(errmsg)
...
```

However, from what you write, it is not quite clear to me why your approach segfaults.

#### Details

- The `typemaps.i` file contains the `float *OUTPUT` typemap, which is then applied to the `float *median` argument and turns this from an argument into a `float` output value. See the SWIG docs on [argument handling](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Arguments) for details.
- The `cstrings.i` file contains SWIG macros to deal with C strings. Here, I used the `%cstring_bounded_output` macro. This creates a `char *` buffer of the given size 1024 and passes this as the argument for `char *msg` automatically. Then, the contents after the function complete are converted into a python string and appended to the output. See [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn12) for details.
- SWIG handles the first two `char *` arguments by default, that is converting python strings to appropriate `char *` and passing these. Note that the passed `char *` for these arguments are immutable, i.e., if your `myfunction` attempts to modify these, bad things will happen. Read about how SWIG handles C strings [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_nn8).
- So, your wrapped `myfunction` then is used as shown above and has the following signature in python:
  `myfunction(infile, maskfile, check) -> (out, median, msg)`

#### EDIT:

The SWIG docs about [`carrays.i`](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#Library_carrays) state:

> **Note:** `%array_functions()` and `%array_class()` should not be used with types of `char` or `char *`.

I think your code is not creating correctly NULL-terminated C `char *`, so perhaps this could be causing the segfaults.

Comment: Thank you @m7thon. This is a really, really good answer: clearly explained, with a well laid-out solution within the context of the original code. The final point regarding the segfaults I suspect is correct too. Some quick queries to follow up: 

- is the correct return order <return_val> then the order of the declarations in the interface file?
- I added a `%typemap(in)` for `char *infile` that uses PyString_AsString($input). If I "deliberately" pass this an `int` from python, it segfaults - how can I make SWIG handle this better? Can it type-check and throw an exception?

Comment: The return order is determined as follows: First, the `$result` (SWIG internal variable) is just the converted (to python) <return_val>. Then, arguments that are converted to outputs (by "argout typemaps") are treated *in the the order in which the arguments appear in the function*, and are normally *appended* to the `$result`. So if you want `median` and `msg` to become outputs, the order will generally be `(return_val, median, msg)`. That being said, you can write your own argout typemaps that *prepend* instead of *append* to `$result`, but the SWIG provided argout typemaps always append.

Comment: If you write your own "in" typemap, you receive a `PyObject*`. You need to check that this is of the correct type (`PyString_Check`) and handle an error accordingly (using e.g. `SWIG_exception(SWIG_RuntimeError, "error message");`). But converting python strings is tricky, since you also need to worry about encoding (byte, unicode). Just let SWIG do the work for you. Have a look at [SWIG's typemap code](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/typemaps/strings.swg#L34) and [SWIG's conversion code](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/python/pystrings.swg#L4).

Answer (score 0):

I am not learn SWIG very deeply.But I try give you some suggestions.
1.
  If your program modifies the input parameter or uses it to return data, consider using the cstring.i library file described in the SWIG Library chapter.
Data is copied into a new Python string and returned.
  If your program needs to work with binary data, you can use a typemap to expand a Python string into a pointer/length argument pair. As luck would have it, just such a typemap is already defined. Just do this:

```
    %apply (char *STRING, int LENGTH) { (char *data, int size) };
   ...
   int parity(char *data, int size, int initial);
```

Python:

```
parity("e\x09ffss\x00\x00\x01\nx", 0)
```

If you need to return binary data, you might use the cstring.i library file. The cdata.i library can also be used to extra binary data from arbitrary pointers.

2.I think "pre-initialising" maybe necessary.